# SCons build object files in source folders, rather have them in "build" folder

Tags: scons

I'm very new to SCons and working on a project, where I am supposed to implement SCons.
The directory layout is like this:

- Folder

  - build
  - subfoldr1

    - subsubfoldr1

      - SConscript1
  - subfoldr2

    - subsubfoldr2

      - SConscript2
  - subfoldr3

    - subsubfoldr3

      - SConscript3
  - SConscript_Main
  - SConstruct

Now when I run the SCons, it builds all the *.o files in all the subfoldrs, I'd rather have it build them in the "build" folder.

SConstruct looks like this:

```py
...
...
SConscript('SConscript_Main', variant_dir='build/temp', src_dir='.', duplicate=0, exports='env')
```

SConscript_Main looks like this:

```py
import ...
directory = str(Dir('#')
obj = []
libraries = []
list = os.listdir(directory)
...
...

def SConscript_files():
    for i in list:
        path = os.path.join(directory, i)
        SConscript_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'SConscript*'))
        for SConscript_file in SConscript_files:
            if 'SConscript' in SConscript_file:
                objects = SConscript(SConscript_file, exports='env')
                obj.append(objects) 
    return(obj)

objects = []

objects.append(get_SConsript_Modules())
xyz = env.Program(target='T_Name', source = objects, LIBS = libraries)
```

Sub-SConscripts look like this:

```py
Import('env')

env = env.Clone()

env.Append(CPPPATH = 'subsubfoldr1')

files = [
    'subsubfoldr1\\BOOT_Init.c',
    'subsubfoldr1\\BOOT_Main.c',
    'subsubfoldr1\\BOOT_StartUpTests.c',
    'subsubfoldr1\\main.c'
]

modules = [ env.StaticObject(x) for x in files ]
Return ('modules')
```

What am I missing? I tried couple of different solutions, but neither worked. For instance, I tried to give all the module specific SConscripts in this line of SConstruct, but the variant_dir gives error:

```py
SConscript(['SConscript_Main', 'subfoldr1/Sconscript1', 'subfoldr2/SConscript2', 'subfoldr3/SConscript3'], variant_dir='build/temp', src_dir='.', duplicate=0, exports='env')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. There's a couple issues with your implementation.

Firstly, you've asked SCons to use a variant_dir of 'build' and source dir of '.'.
This is not a good idea because the effectively build is in the source dir.

Secondly, if all your SConscripts populate `modules` and then `Return()` them,  each subsequent SConscript will overwrite the return value from the previous SConscript. Note you could just append the return values from `StaticObjects()` to an env variable

```
for x in files:
  env['MODULES'] += env.StaticObject(x)
```

Thirdly, the logic in your SConscript_main, should probably just be in your SConstruct. Then each SConscript() call can set the variant_dir to `"#/build/"+os.path.dirname(SConscript_file)`

Lastly, since you've told the top level SConscript to use a variant_dir='build', when the various SConscripts are run, SCons considers their current directory to be under `build`, and given that you have duplicate=0, python's own glob() (fairly certain) won't find any files under build/....

Here's a possible re-implementation of `SConscript_files()` to put in your SConstruct

Sample SConstruct

```
import os.path

env = Environment()


def SConscript_files(env):
    sconscripts = Glob("*/*/SConscript", strings=True)
    return sconscripts


objs = []
env["MODULES"] = []
x = SConscript_files(env)
for f in x:
    print("File:%s" % f)
    sconscript_dir = os.path.dirname(f)
    SConscript(
        f,
        variant_dir=os.path.join("#/build", sconscript_dir),
        duplicate=False,
        src_dir=sconscript_dir,
        exports="env",
    )


print("MODULES:%s" % [str(o) for o in env["MODULES"]])
```

Sample `b/c/SConscript`

```
Import('env')
print("In b/c/SConscript")
files = ['x.c', 'y.c']

for f in files:
    env['MODULES'] += env.StaticObject(f)

print("MODULES:%s"%[str(o) for o in env['MODULES']])
```

Output from sample:

```
% python ~/devel/scons/git/as_scons/scripts/scons.py
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
File:b/c/SConscript
In b/c/SConscript
MODULES:['x.o', 'y.o']
MODULES:['build/b/c/x.o', 'build/b/c/y.o']
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o build/b/c/x.o -c b/c/x.c
gcc -o build/b/c/y.o -c b/c/y.c
scons: done building targets.

% tree .
.
├── SConstruct
├── b
│   └── c
│       ├── SConscript
│       ├── x.c
│       └── y.c
└── build
    └── b
        └── c
            ├── x.o
            └── y.o
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. I have been trying to understand, it is understandable. but How about the SConscript_Main. In the original post, as I showed that there's a SConscript in the same level as SConstruct. and then there are sub-SConscripts. that is what I am now missing in order to make connection.

Comment: You no longer need the SConscript_Main.  In general you should not have your variant dir be a subdirectory of the source directory. It can cause recursive issues...  SConscript_Main's only purpose was to be used with the variant_dir specification in a way which is not recommended. So the logic was moved into the SConsctruct, which calls SConscript() on each subdirs SConscript with the proper variant_dir setup.  Does that answer your question?  Why do you think you need SConscript_Main?